# Model a linear regression, having as input a vector

Tags: arrays, pandas, matrix, scikit-learn

I am trying to put as one of my model variables a vector, but I get the error 'setting an array element with a sequence'. Do you know how to fix it?
Here is the input I am trying to set:

```
array([-2.33369276e-01,  2.56486446e-01,  3.80100965e-01, -2.56408364e-01,
        4.21026260e-01,  4.87683117e-01,  2.74534702e-01,  7.16617703e-01,
        3.99567425e-01, -1.01365648e-01, -7.30723441e-02, -8.06054294e-01,
        2.67650783e-01,  6.82212114e-02, -3.28384072e-01,  8.80505145e-03,
        2.16574326e-01, -5.89917228e-03, -4.02390242e-01, -3.65484916e-02,
       -2.17340693e-01, -4.55826521e-01, -1.41737625e-01,  2.05082536e-01,
       -3.68351005e-02,  1.44978404e-01, -2.09171444e-01, -2.81268544e-03,
        2.58173972e-01, -3.19096655e-01,  3.30500826e-02, -2.21092448e-01])
```

My goal is to model, for example with a linear regression.

```
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
 

regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Where X_train is:

```
2      [-0.206250757, 0.263976961, 0.343763083, -0.14...
3      [-0.233369276, 0.256486446, 0.380100965, -0.25...
6      [-0.368456453, 0.438601553, 0.047115989, 0.399...
8      [-0.255798995, 0.419841707, 0.189137682, 0.114...
10     [0.05540955, 0.4429106, 0.30668178, 0.47204316...
                             ...                        
171    [-0.0589945093, 0.585331142, 0.187265143, -0.2...
172    [-0.120263539, -0.0903587192, -0.0877718553, 0...
174    [-0.14658886, -0.16904959, 0.06344877, -0.5205...
175    [0.0401920676, 0.0129625741, 0.0995061696, 0.2...
176    [-0.107441947, 0.279930115, -0.0112578124, -0....
Name: prueba_2, Length: 100, dtype: object
```

And y_train:

```
2      4
3      5
6      5
8      4
10     4
      ..
171    2
172    2
174    1
175    4
176    1
```

But I get this error:

'setting an array element with a sequence.'